# Class_Terminate not firing on object from form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a very simple form, that uses a very simple class to handle some things. And that class has a `Class_Terminate` sub to clean up after itself. However, that doesn't seem to be firing when the form gets closed.

**MCVE:**

Form Form1, one text box named Text0, no further controls

```
Private myClass1 As Class1

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set myClass1 = New Class1
    myClass1.InitForm Me
End Sub
```

Class Class1

```
Public theForm As Form
Private WithEvents SomeTextbox As TextBox
Public Sub InitForm(frm As Form)
    Set theForm = frm
    Set SomeTextbox = frm.Text0
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    MsgBox "Class1 terminated succesfully"
End Sub
```

However, the class terminate handler doesn't fire when I close the form.

I tried unsetting the *Form* object in the class:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Set myClass1.theForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

But chaos ensued: The class terminate handler fires after closing the form, but immediately afterwards Access hard-crashes without any error message!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access doesn't gracefully clean up the form object when you close a form.

That means: if an object has open references to a form, the form object persists. It only can get removed by the garbage collector if there are no references to it.

The first version of the form was creating a memory leak: the form object `Form_Form1` had a reference to `Class1` (through the `MyClass1` variable), `Class1` had a reference to the form object through the `theForm` variable. This caused a reference loop. The terminate handler didn't fire because the class never terminated, it remained in memory indefinitely, and closing and reopening the form just opened up a new instance of the class.

The second version caused a problem: while the reference loop was broken, references to `Form1` were released first (because there still was a reference to `Class1` on `Form1`), causing the garbage collector to clean that up, then references to `Class1` were released and the garbage collector tried to clean up `Class1`, including the textbox object `SomeTextbox`, causing Access to hard-crash since the form object was already cleaned up and the textbox object was invalid.

The solution is to break the reference loop by removing all references to `Class1` first. This doesn't cause crashes.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Set myClass1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

This causes the garbage collector to clean up the Class1 instance first, releasing references to Text0, then cleans up the form objects because no-one has open references to that.